# Changing Android Numpad's "Next" to "Go" on submit

Tags: android, html, forms, mobile, keyboard

Making a mobile friendly site, I have a single field and a submit button. The field is just for numbers - like a zip code, so I have `type="tel"` in the input, which pulls up the numpad.

Problem with that the **"Go"** is replaced by **"Next"**, I need the numpad to display while showing **"Go"** for quick and easy submission.

Wondering if this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Android, a type=tel field pulls up a keyboard with different characters, such as “(” and “W”, in addition to digits, and there is no “Go” or “Next” anywhere. So it sounds like you would like to change the basic user interface of some Android versions.

The type=tel attribute means that the field is for telephone number input, and browsers may deal with it in different ways that are regarded as suitable for such data. They can for example check that the data conforms to some phone number syntax (which may mean several things) or default to the device’s own phone number or access a phonebook in the system. Thus, using it just to pull up a numpad may lead to unexpected trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this to simulate the event.

You can detect the `next` keyboard press by using the following bind in JQuery:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.which === 9) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```

The `next` button emulates the tab keypress event on a keyboard, which is key code 9. Unfortunately, `keypress` and `keyup` events do not detect the next key event, so you need to bind it on `keydown`.

Hope that helps!